# Shooting RAW vs 4:2:2 10-bit HDR PQ for HDR output

Tags: premiere, canon, raw, hdr

With the Canon EOS R5 I can choose to record in 12 bit RAW (DCI) or 10-bit HDR PQ H.265 (All-I or IPB compressed).

Is there a big advantage of shooting in RAW vs HDR PQ for non professional HDR output?

Comment: It’s not RAW vs 10bit HDR PQ. That’s apples and oranges. It’s RAW vs Canon compressed(?) log, and either one of them is capable of covering PQ, but 10 bits is just enough to deliver as HDR — you want to record at 12-16 and cut it down, if you can. Netflix requires it.  Actually, you should check out the technical docs they publish, especially their camera requirements, for an idea about what’s important in a camera. It’s a good resource.

Comment: Would you say 12 bit RAW would make a big difference compared to 10 bit Canon log for HRD output?

Comment: The RAW is better, but if you stacked them side-by-side, normalized, you'd be hard pressed to tell the difference, visually.  Where you'd notice a difference is when you're trying to do color qualifications --  say like selecting all of a particular red and increasing the luminance, or keying a greenscreen -- that's where you'd see more noise in the 10-bit log, but it's still very usable.  IDK the specs on those cameras, but usually, if one does RAW, it'll also have the option to do compressed log.  The codec they're shooting will also be a factor in how smoothly you can edit.  H.265 no bueno.

Comment: I was wrong. Netflix only requires 10 bit log, but still...  https://partnerhelp.netflixstudios.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000579527-Cameras-and-Image-Capture

Comment: Oh, wow.  Those are some nice specs.  Those both look like good cameras.  HEIF is H.265, so you'll need a GPU that can decode that well, or else transcode it.